# Want to customize Pricebook and then export it into excel in a proper format

Tags: reporting, pricebook

As we cannot customize Pricebook nor can we add a custom button, I have an issue.
Actually I want to download a pricebook in excel format, which i can do using report with Printable view option. But that does not provide the ability to customize the format, color, etc in printable view. Is there any way I can customize my report for downloading it into excel?

Thanks,

Sarika Patel

Answer (score 0):

You can create Visual force page for the price book as per your design and you can export it as excel.

for exporting Visual force page as Excel please visit below link

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003176

Keyur Modi